# How to use x-editable to submit a form

Tags: php, form-submit, x-editable

I'm trying to submit my data  to my php function (My app is based on an MVC framework), but all it does is erasing my data.

Here is my code in php that i want to replace by an inline x-editable:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo URL; ?>mylist/editSave/<?php echo $this->oneList->list_id; ?>">
        <label>Change my list name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="list_name" value="<?php echo $this->oneList->list_name; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value='Change' />
</form>
```

I have tried to do this:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-name="'.$value->list_name.'" data-url="'. URL . 'mylist/editSave/' . $value->list_id.'" data-value="'.$value->list_name.'">Edit</a></td>';
```

But it doesn't work. What i want to do, is send `$value->list_id` and my new `$value->list_name` which has to be received by my php function `URL/mylist/editSave/`

Please help!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use success method with own function formatXEditable and you must always disable default display function.

```
    function formatXEditable($item, $val){
        $val = $val.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
        $($item).text($val);
        $($item).on('shown', function(e, editable) {
            editable.input.$input.val($val);
        });
    }

    $('#identifier').editable({
        ...
        display: function(value, response) {
            return false;   //disable this method (success displays value information)
        },
        success: function(response, value) {
            if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg; //msg will be shown in editable form

            formatXEditable($('#identifier'), response.identifier);
            $('#pagesForm-identifier').val(response.identifier);
        },
        error: function(errors) { }
    });
```

Hope it helps.